# Save a database query and update it automatically every X hours. Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, store

i'm a beginner and i need some help to optimize my "All Posts" page.

I have a page with all my published posts (300+). I display them whit this code:

```
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?> 
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
    <?php the_title();?></a>
        <?php 
            global $wpdb;
            $postid = $post->ID;
            $postTit = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT posttitle FROM wp_posts WHERE ID=" . $postid);
            echo "{$postTit}";
        ?>
    <div class="comments">
        <?php 
            global $wpdb;
            $postid = $post->ID;
            $commCount = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT comment_count FROM wp2_posts WHERE ID=" . $postid);
            echo "{$commCount }";
        ?>
    </div>
<?php endwhile;
```

**The question is:**

I was thinking to "store" the query and update it hourly. I tried to Google something about it without success. I'll appreciate if someone can tell me at least what i need to search since i'm a beginner in these kind of things.

(Sorry for bad English)

**Edit 1**

You guys think its a good idea to convert Data from MySQL to JSON using PHP and update it every hour ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [wp_cron()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron) function for automatic save and updating purpose:

```
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'my_task_hook' ) ) {
  wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'my_task_hook' );
}

add_action( 'my_task_hook', 'my_task_function' );
function my_task_function() {
  wp_mail( 'your@email.com', 'Automatic email', 'Automatic scheduled email from WordPress.');
}
```

You will need to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: I'm not at home right now, when i get back, ill learn more about wp_cron() and let you know. Thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome… take your time and try it as you want :)

Comment: I tried to read something about wp_cron, and i can say thats not the best way to do it, and seems quite hard to do :(

Comment: wp_cron is used mostly by nearly all backup plugins and other plugins that need automation tasks related to time or to website visits… The other way is to use the cron of your host server to trigger a script on your wordpress web site

Comment: Maybe i found how to use wp_cron() properly, ill let you know tomorrow if it works :)

Comment: I think that is not so complicated … Yes please tell me.

Comment: Yeah! I'm so happy! It works perfectly :) I'll edit the main when i finish the full code so you can take a look at it if you want. It was super easy with wp_cron :) Thanks a lot!